# Some applications don't appear in a registry query

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, registry, tortoisesvn

I'm using the following C# code in order to get information about installed apps:

```
string registry_key = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";

using(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(registry_key))
{
    foreach(string subkey_name in key.GetSubKeyNames())
    {
        using(RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(subkey_name))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(subkey.GetValue("DisplayName"));
        }
    }
}
```

When I'm running this code as a standalone project - all works fine.

**BUT**: when I'm running this code as part of my entire project, some of the apps do not appear. Actually, the missing apps are part of the 3rdParty apps I'm using for my project (to remove any doubts, I'm using the same user and permissions on both cases).

Any idea how to find the missing apps?

Comment: Are they both running as the exact same user? Are they both running as administrator? Are they both running in 64-bit?

Comment: Yes. As I mentioned, same conditions for both projects. the only difference is that the other project has some 3rd party apps, and the missing apps are some of them.

Comment: Then how about also looking in registry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`

Comment: Thanks but this won’t answer my question, why the apps are missing only when I run the code via the primary project...

Comment: @YonatanNethanel - the reason they are missing is because there **_is_** some undetermined difference between the two. [*grin*] ///// are you certain that  both are calling powershell with the same bit-ness? you can run PoSh in 32bit or 64bit mode ... so it's worth checking to see what you are actually running. you can do that thus >>>  `[environment]::Is64BitProcess` <<< from inside the powershell instance.

Comment: @Theo, thanks for your help, the "Wow6432Node" solved the issue.